# Creating classes with a lot of imported functions here and there

Tags: python, class, oop, object, encapsulation

Let's say i have a lot of functions in `alotoffunc.py` that is used by more than 1 type of object.

Let's say `ObjectI` and `ObjectII` and `ObjectXI` all uses some functions in `alotoffunc.py`. And each of the Object were using different set of functions but all the objects have the variable `object.table`.

`alotoffunc.py`:

```
def abc(obj, x):
  return obj.table(x) * 2

def efg(obj, x):
  return obj.table(x) * obj.table(x)

def hij(obj, x, y):
  return obj.table(x) * obj.table(y)

def klm(obj, x, y):
  return obj.table(x) *2 - obj.table(y)
```

And then i import the functions and overload them:

```
import alotoffunc

class ObjectI:
  def abc(self, x):
    return alotoffunc.abc(self, x)

  def efg(self, x):
    return alotoffunc.efg(self, x)

class ObjectII:
  def efg(self, x):
    return alotoffunc.efg(self, x)
  def klm(self, x, y): 
    return alotoffunc.klm(self, x, y)

class ObjectXI:
  def abc(self, x):
    return alotoffunc.abc(self, x)
  def klm(self, x, y):
    return alotoffunc.klm(self, x, y)
```

It looks a like a big mess now, how should I go about building my object class and arrange my `alotoffunc.py`?

Comment: It doesn't look like a mess to me. If it bothers you, you can have a base class that implements all the methods then override the unnecessary ones to raise a `NotImplementedError` in the subclasses, or consolidate method groups into mixins.

Comment: I agree with Selcuk.  What you did looks reasonable.  Subclassing might reduce the amount of code slightly, but may also sacrifice clarity since you would be overriding functions you don't want rather than adding functions that you do want.

Comment: mixins sounds good but controling polymorphism might give me a headache later, any hints on how to handle that after i use mixins?

Comment: I don't understand why you think this looks like a big mess, can you explain what about it is messy?

Comment: From an OOP perspective from C/Java, I should have created a class hierarchy and inherit the classes appropriately. But in python, i couldn't figure out what is the best way to do that. That's why i think it's quite messy with somewhat repeated code that i can save when developing.

Comment: @alvas You may need to have a common mixin/abstract class to make it easier. If there is no common behaviour you can even have a dummy common base class. A real world example of what you are trying to accomplish would help.

Comment: they're like algorithms of the same purpose but using different mathematical algorithms to achieve them. Usually people build one algorithm with the math and then rebuild the math in the next algorithm. I wanted to simplify it and put them into one single library instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) You can have a base class that implements all the methods then override the unnecessary ones to raise a `NotImplementedError` in the subclasses.

(2) You can have mixins to reduce repetition:

```
import alotoffunc

class MixinAbc:
    def abc(self, x):
        return alotoffunc.abc(self, x)

class MixinEfg:
    def efg(self, x):
        return alotoffunc.efg(self, x)

class MixinKlm:
    def klm(self, x, y):
        return alotoffunc.klm(self, x, y)

class ObjectI(MixinAbc, MixinEfg):
    pass

class ObjectII(MixinEfg, MixinKlm):
    pass    

class ObjectXI(MixinAbc, MixinKlm):
    pass
```

You can also combine this method with that of @cpburnz.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to bind the desired functions directly as instance methods to a class in its definition. Note that each function will receive `self` as the first argument.

```
import alotoffunc

class ObjectI:
  abc = alotoffunc.abc
  efg = alotoffunc.efg

class ObjectII:
  efg = alotoffunc.efg
  klm = alotoffunc.klm

class ObjectXI:
  abc = alotoffunc.abc
  klm = alotoffunc.klm
```

This can be a simpler approach to defining mix-in classes if there isn't a clear, logical grouping for the various functions. The grouping does depend on your use case though so the mix-in approach can be better depending on the situation.

Answer (score 5):

If I wanted to avoid mixins, perhaps in order to minimize the opacity of my code, I would just do it like this:

```
class ObjectI:
    from alotoffunc import abc, efg

class ObjectII:
    from alotoffunc import efg, klm

class ObjectXI:
    from alotoffunc import abc, klm
```

The imported methods automatically get bound whenever you create instances of the class. In other words, they are instance methods by default.

In case you want them to be static methods, use [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) as follows:

```
class ObjectI:
    from alotoffunc import abc, efg
    abc = staticmethod(abc)
```

Also I wouldn't worry too much about performance issues from having these multiple import statements, because Python is smart enough to only run an imported module once and then save it in memory in case it's needed later.

In case the functions you want to import have some sort of logical groupings, then you should definitely either use mixins, or organize the functions into separate "mixin modules" so that perhaps you can even do `from mixinmodule import *`. For the mixin-class approach, I think the regular import statement works better than the from-import, unless your function names are very long and you only want to type them once!

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
from alotoffunc import *
```

And then, if -for example- we have the variables `o1`, `o2` , which are instances of `Object1` and `Object2`, we can do:

```
abc(o1,x)
efg(o2,x)
...
```

It is not so 'pretty' as the OO approach of calling o1.abc(x), but it is so much maintainable than having to override all the methods.

What the `from ___ import *` does is to free you of having to use the package name like `alotoffunc.abc` and so on.

## Edit

As @JamesKing comments, this solution does not work if you have a function with the same name inside of your classes. As they seem useless -they just call the imported functions- I was thinking of removing them. If this does not work with your code, you should use `from ___ import ___ as ___` as he said.

Comment: Take a closer look. The function inside the Class have the same name as the function imported. Maybe `from...import...as...`

Comment: That it is true, but it looks he is just creating those functions to use the imported ones. In my solution I was thinking of removing those functions from the class. I will edit my answer to make that clear!

Comment: The problem is that i don't want `ObjectII` to do `abc()`. By doing importing everything, it resolves the coding redundancy but later i've deal with users calling anything they like even when the object is not suppose to allow it. Nevertheless it's a solution.

Answer (score 3):

This is a "factory" approach.  Might be over complicated if you don't have that many functions, but if you truly have "a lot", it might work out.

```
import alotoffunc

class Builder(object):
    def __init__(self, objtype):
        objtypes = { 'ObjectI': ['abc', 'efg'],
                     'ObjectII': ['efg', 'klm'],
                     'ObjectXI': ['abc', 'klm']}

        for func in objtypes[objtype]:
            self.__dict__[func] = getattr(alotoffunc, func)
```

Comment: cool, i didn't think that `getattr()` could be used that way.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
import alotoffunc
import types

class ObjectI:
    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self, abc, types.MethodType(alotoffunc.abc, self))
        setattr(self, efg, types.MethodType(alotoffunc.efg, self))

class ObjectII:
    def __init__(self):
        setattr(self, efg, types.MethodType(alotoffunc.efg, self))
        setattr(self, klm, types.MethodType(alotoffunc.klm, self))

class ObjectXI:
    # ...
```

(There might be some flaws or typos, but the basic idea is correct. I use something similar in my code.

This binds the original functions to each instance on creation. setattr() is not necessary, but I prefer this to signal that there happens some "magic".

I'm pretty sure there is a better way to create the methods in the class object, but this might require metaclasses and/or more magic.

Answer (score 1):

I think a cleaner way to achieve your goal is to use the multiple inheritance feature of python. Many programmers hate MI, claiming that it produces messy code or that it's hard to maintain. As long as you're careful when planning your classes, using MI can be very helpful.

[One of the many links returned by Google](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_multiple_inheritance.php)

SomeClasses.py -- Normally each class is store in a separate file.

```
class ABCClass:
    def abc(obj, x):
    return obj.table(x) * 2

class DEFClass:
    def efg(obj, x):
        return obj.table(x) * obj.table(x)

class HIJClass:
    def hij(obj, x, y):
        return obj.table(x) * obj.table(y)

class KLMClass:
    def klm(obj, x, y):
        return obj.table(x) *2 - obj.table(y)
```

TheProject.py -- no extra code is needed unless you actually need to override the functionality of the base classes.

```
import SomeClasses #or each class file

class ObjectI (ABCClass, EFGClass):
    pass

class ObjectII (EFGClass, KLMClass):
    pass

class ObjectXI (ABCClass, KLMClass):
    pass
```

Of course this is a trivial example, where each base class only has a single function. A real example that comes to mind is when packing images onto a shared texture resource. You want the functionality that comes PIL.Image, but be able to store the images as leaf nodes in a home-brewed tree data structure. You can use multiple inheritance to gain the methods of both classes using minimal code. LeafImage would have all the methods of both classes, and when you decide to modify TreeLeaf, no additional code will be needed in LeafImage.

```
class LeafImage (PIL.Image, TreeLeaf):
    pass
```